# how to add drop down list in a detailview control

Tags: asp.net

How can I put a drop down list in a DetailView control?  I have converted the field into template but having some issues when I add the drop down list, basically it is not binding the data into my table.  I simply want to have some static data in the drop down but it should save it when I hit the Update button.  I have the DetailView in a Edit mode.  Thanks

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="Post_ID" 
            DataSourceID="MyDataSource" ForeColor="Black" Height="50px" 
            Width="805px" DefaultMode="Edit">
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#003366" 
                BorderStyle="Groove" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Post_ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Post_ID" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" 
                    SortExpression="CategoryList">



                     <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("CategoryList") %>'
                            Height="20px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>




                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("CategoryList") %>'
                            Height="20px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryList") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" Runat="server"   >
           <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </EditItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void dvItem_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dvItem.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
       DropDownList control= (DropDownList)this.dvItem.FindControl("IdDDL");
       ..          
    }
}
```

Selection

```
protected void dvItem_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
       DropDownList control = (DropDownList)this.dvItem.FindControl("IdDDL");
}
```

Comment: thanks but this code is giving me all kind of errors specially the CurrentMode and i am not sure idDDL overall i could not follow the code as i am newbie. i would appreciate if u can simplify. thanks

Answer (score 0):

its simple,just convert your field to Template Field and click on DetailsView's smart tag then select Edit Templates then in EditItem Template's field add DropDownList with static Data and in EditDataBindings Set BoundTo Property.

like this :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("yourField") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: thanks i did exactly what you said but the problem is Binding for Selected Value is grayed out, only custom binding selected is active

Comment: how bind your DetailsView with Code Or Wirzard? when you use code apporach just Custom Binding is Active.

Comment: i am still stuck here can someone give me some clear explanation about this issue?  thanks